# Aggregated SUM from "Referencing entity" relationship, how to include nodes without relationship

Tags: views

I have two content types - `contact` and `payment`. Payment have `field_contact` that is an reference to `contact` and also `field_payment_amount` which is decimal.

In views I'm showing list of contacts (with filter by type = contact) but also would like to show SUM of payments for given contact. I added relationship: `Entity Reference: Referencing entity` to entities that are referencing my contact by field `field_contact`, turned on aggregation, and added to view `field_payment_amount` aggregated as SUM, and using my relationship. In this configuration all contacts are shown but field that should show my sum is empty.

Next I added another filter (by type), now using my relationship and for this relationship filtering by type = payment. In this configuration I can see my sums - great! But! If contact have no payments - it is excluded from table completely.

How can I show contacts without payments with "0" as sum of payments and calculate proper sums for contacts with payments? I feel like I'm missing something simple, or maybe not?

**Added:**

Ok, I reduced problem to most simple case, and analyzed query. Now interesting thing is that looks like the same query executed manually by me, and by view - gives different results O_o .

Query:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, MIN(field_contact_node.nid) AS field_contact_node_nid, 'node' AS field_data_field_payment_amount_node_entity_type, SUM(field_contact_node__field_data_field_payment_amount.field_payment_amount_value) AS field_contact_node__field_data_field_payment_amount_field_pa
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_contact} field_data_field_contact ON node.nid = field_data_field_contact.field_contact_target_id AND (field_data_field_contact.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_contact.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {node} field_contact_node ON field_data_field_contact.entity_id = field_contact_node.nid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_payment_amount} field_contact_node__field_data_field_payment_amount ON field_contact_node.nid = field_contact_node__field_data_field_payment_amount.entity_id AND (field_contact_node__field_data_field_payment_amount.entity_type = 'node' AND field_contact_node__field_data_field_payment_amount.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('contact')) ))
GROUP BY nid, field_data_field_payment_amount_node_entity_type
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

Views output:

[image: Views]

Query manual execution result:

[image]

Does anyone have possible explanation of this interesting behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got this working by doing basically what you did:

**Relationship:** Content referencing Content from field_contact, do not tick 'Require this relationship'

**Aggregation:** Yes

**Fields:**

1. Title: no relationship
2. payment amount: set relationship to Content referencing Content from field_contact. Set no results behavior to '0'. Set aggregation to 'SUM', Group column to 'Value'

Works fine.

**Exported View**

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Entity Reference: Referencing entity */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_contact_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_contact_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_contact_node']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_contact_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_contact_node';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Field: SUM(Content: payment_amount) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_payment_amount']['id'] = 'field_payment_amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_payment_amount']['table'] = 'field_data_field_payment_amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_payment_amount']['field'] = 'field_payment_amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_payment_amount']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_contact_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_payment_amount']['group_type'] = 'sum';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_payment_amount']['empty'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_payment_amount']['settings'] = array(
  'thousand_separator' => ' ',
  'decimal_separator' => '.',
  'scale' => '2',
  'prefix_suffix' => 1,
);
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'contact' => 'contact',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'test';
```

Comment: Can you please export your view and paste it here?

Comment: Thanks, but I meant view and not query :) .

Comment: I suggest you do a new test install of Drupal and recreate it there for yourself.

Comment: Just an afterthought, did you see step 2 re. Set no results behavior to '0'

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I was at the point of your view before, and the problem is, that it is not aggregating payments properly. I added payment, and still have all "0" everywhere. I'm going to try this out on other installment of Drupal.

Comment: Uuh, it's worst case scenario - it actually works on other installation. Well not worst, because it's not production and can be easily recreated yet interesting bug I got there. Thanks for help, it assured me that I'm not crazy :) .

Answer (score 1):

I was debugging like crazy to figure this out and then after checking some values in views_handler_field_field I realized what was wrong, and for sure it weren't Views! I forgot, or rather though of it as irrelevant, that there was third content type - a comment, that had a field "field_contact". The problem occurred because Views when summing up, was also using existing "comment" nodes, but because they didn't have "field_payment_amount" at all - Views got confused. So the real answer is that we need to filter out any additional types that are using "field_contact" field in our relationship.

I guess Views could act a bit better on this, and not get confused but use only available fields from proper nodes to create a sum, but it isn't much problem as long as we can filter out useless (for SUM) types that are using our reference field.

This explains why I got random/wrong results without type filtering on relationship, but when I added filter for "payment" - I didn't get "0" results, because then view assumed that relationship is required. The proper solution is then EXCLUDING wrong types that are in our relationship.